# XML node value VB.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode

I'm trying to extract an value from inside a node, but cannot seem to get it to work. I want to get the value= from name="Container.DeviceId"

```
<coreProperties>    
    <coreProperty name="Common.ApplicationHome" value="1" />
    <coreProperty name="Common.InstallationHome" value="2" />
    <coreProperty name="Container.DeviceId" value="3"/>
    <coreProperty name="Service.DeviceID" value="4/>
    <coreProperty name="Service.DeviceType" value="5" />
    <coreProperty name="Service.LocationID" value="6" />
</coreProperties>
```

this is what I have so far

```
doc.Load(file1)
Dim root As XmlNode = doc.DocumentElement
Dim nodeDeviceId As XmlNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/coreProperties/coreProperty[@name='Container.DeviceId']")
Dim deviceID As String = nodeDeviceId.Attributes.ItemOf("value").InnerText
```

Comment: your code worked fine for me, `deviceID` contained value `3`

Comment: strange. im using it as part of a custom action in an MSI. Without it the MSI installs. With  it included it the MSI fails. Ive tried debugging the customer action with no luck, so thought I was calling something else, or something along those lines.